# Making a custom laravel directive to detect if view is served on mobile or desktop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have created this directive in my `AppServiceProvider` and this is the code

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Blade;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    Blade::directive('detect', function () {
     if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
       $user_ag = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       if(preg_match('/(Mobile|Android|Tablet|GoBrowser|[0-9]x[0-9]*|uZardWeb\/|Mini|Doris\/|Skyfire\/|iPhone|Fennec\/|Maemo|Iris\/|CLDC\-|Mobi\/)/uis',$user_ag)){
          return true;
       };
    };
    return false;
         });
    }
}
```

I now want to use it inside my blade file like this

```
 <div class="mb-3  
    @if(detect)         
     col-6     
    @else
    col-3       
    @endif
    expand_on_mobile">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Category</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
  </div>
```

If the view is being served on mobile i want to display the class `col-6` but display `col-3` if its being served on desktop.

So far i get the error `undefined constant detect`.

How can i fix this?

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#custom-if-statements.

Comment: @Lucas Yeah that's what was missing. Thanks.

Comment: `detect` is not defined. Blade directives are prefixed with an `@` symbol. Your code would be `@detect`, but even then, wouldn't do anything. You're probably looking for `Blade::if('detect', ...)` (linked in Lucas's comment), then you'd be able to do `@detect ... @elsedetect ... @enddetect`

Comment: @TimLewis I managed to solve the problem.

Comment: Haha yup, just saw your answer below  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it this way. In my `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
   Blade::if('detect', function ($value) {
      if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
   $user_ag = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
   if(preg_match('/(Mobile|Android|Tablet|GoBrowser|[0-9]x[0-9]*|uZardWeb\/|Mini|Doris\/|Skyfire\/|iPhone|Fennec\/|Maemo|Iris\/|CLDC\-|Mobi\/)/uis',$user_ag)){
      return 'mobile';
   };
    }else{
    return 'desktop';
    }
});
```

and i am using it this way

```
<div  

@detect("mobile")
class="mb-3 col-6 "
@else
class="mb-3 col-3 " 
@enddetect

    >
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Category</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to overcomplicate the process bootstrap has media statements already handled :) look at this link to help all you need to do is add col-sm-3 for mobile or col-md-6 when it gets to any higher than a tablet [Boostrap docs to column responsiveness](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content)